# Passing on all directives to a child element of the component

Tags: angular, angular4-forms

I have a few custom directives which are basically designed for `<input>`.
And I have a custom component `<app-decorated-input>`

There are a ton `<app-decorated-input>`s along with simple `<input>`s in my application for some of which I like to use the directives and for others I don't. How do I pass on the directives to the underlying `<input>` when the directive is used like so:

```
<app-decorated-input directive1 directive2 ></app-decorated-input>
```

and have the same effect of the directives on the underlying `<input>` as if it were used directly on it:

```
 <input type="text" directive1 directive2 >
```

### UPDATE:

What lies inside `<app-decorated-input>` is not much of relevance except the fact that it contains an `<input>` as I have already mentioned. Its template looks something similar to:

```
<div> Some decorations here </div>
<div> 
  <input type="text" {...directives}> <!-- In ReactJS this is done by using {...this.props} -->
</div>
<div> Some decorations here too! </div>
```

All I want to do is transfer all the directives specified on the `<app-decorated-input>` to the underlying `<input>`.

Comment: Did you find a solution for that?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @dcp3450, not yet

Answer (score 1):

You can make every directive provide itself like it is done with `ControlValueAccessor` or validators

```
export const MY_DIRECTIVES = new InjectionToken<any>('MyDirectives');
```

```
export const MY_DIRECTIVE1: Provider = {
  provide: MY_DIRECTIVES,
  useExisting: forwardRef(() => MyDirective1),
  multi: true
};

@Directive({
  selector: '....',
  providers: [MY_DIRECTIVE1]
})
class MyDirective1 {}
```

and then in your input component

```
constructor(@Optional() @Self() @Inject(MY_DIRECTIVES) private myDirectives: any[]) {
  console.log(myDirectives);
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate this a bit more? If I add that in my custom component constructor, I get a cyclic dependency issue. Or are you talking about the native Input element? Then how to pass to the contructor?

Comment: I'd suggest you create a new question with your code that causrs the error.

Comment: Well the question is basically the same, just with a ion-input (from ionic2) instead of input. I don't think it's that much about the error, I'm just not sure where to put it.

Answer (score 0):

In the constructor of the directive you can do some like.

```
constructor(
    @Attribute('attributeName') private attributeUno:String, 
    private element:ElementRef
) {
    console.log(this.attributeUno);
}
```