# Angular components passing parameter free attributes

Tags: angular

I have a component that imports and uses another to include a `mat-table` and I need to pass attributes to the table

about.component.ts:

```
<my-component multiTemplateDataRows flex layout-fill></my-component>
```

desired result in my-table.component.ts:

```
<table mat-table multiTemplateDataRows flex layout-fill>...</table>
```

I would be ok doing this as well:

```
<my-component attributes="multiTemplateDataRows flex layout-fill"></my-component>
```

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: @MassimoCosta nothing yet, lol. Not 100% where to start.

Comment: Could you write your html structure detailed? the table is inside `my-component` and you want to pass attrs from parent component?

Comment: @The.Bear I updated the question slightly, maybe that'll help

Comment: start writing a [mcve] with about.component and my-table.component.

Comment: @MassimoCosta I don't really have an error I'm tackling that can be tested. It's more like I need to pass something to a component and have it be an empty attribute/directive but don't know how.

Comment: My issue/question is the same as this but it doesn't have a selected answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46968558/passing-on-all-directives-to-a-child-element-of-the-component